# GSON: converting a .json file to a JsonObject

Tags: json, gson

Of course, for this i used JsonParser, Here is my Code:

```
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\Projects\\elastic-search-single-log-result.json"));
    JsonObject jobject = (JsonObject) object;
    String message = jobject.get("msg").toString();
    return message;
```

However, the msg is a stack trace enclosed by triple quotes, and it gives me a Malformed Json Exception, at the second line shown above.

I saw stuff about JsonReader having a getLenientMethod, I was wondering if there was something similar for this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it --- I simply had to remove the triple quotes, and I get the JSON file from kibana (which formatted the stack trace a little differently). I hope this helps anyone in the future who will have the same problem